# Visual Studio Team System 2010 Beta 1 is stuck during download. What gives?

Tags: windows-7, installation, download, visual-studio

I'm trying to download the software on Windows 7 RC, but it's stuck:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Wait until it moves out of the "beta" stage. :P

Comment: How long have you waited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download an entire [ISO Image](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=255FC5F1-15AF-4FE7-BE4D-263A2621144B&displaylang=en) of the beta, and mount it with something like [Daemon Tools Lite](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/home) as opposed to using the web installer.